# Set bean property from xpath payload

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-el, spelevaluationexception

I trying make like this:

```
<bean id="xsl1" class="com.transformation.XsltPayloadTransformer">
    <property name="xslResource" value="#xpath('/root/someNode/text()', payload)">
</bean>
```

but it doesn`t work.

Also, I am trying this:

```
<si:header-enricher id="environmentHeaderEnricher"
    input-channel="inputChannel"
    output-channel="prepareChannel">
  <!-- <si-xml:header name="environment" xpath-expression-ref="environmentXpathExpression"/> -->
  <si:header name="environment" expression="#xpath(payload, '/message/xslt', 'string')"/>
</si:header-enricher>
.....

    <bean id="xsl1" class="transformation.XsltPayloadTransformer">
        <property name="xslResource" value="#{headers.get('environment')}">
    </bean>
```

and I getting:

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException:
>   EL1008E:(pos 0): Property or field 'headers' cannot be found on object
>   of type
>   'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' -
>   maybe not public?     at
>   org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:215)
>     at
>   org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:85)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you missunderstood a bit the difference between `Bean Definition SpEL` and `Spring Integration Runtime SpEL`.

Any `<bean>` SpEL works only once at application startup phase and has the scope only with Bean Factory environment.

The Spring Integration SpEL works at runtime on each component invocation and uses `Message` as root object in most cases. Those expressions are performed every time, when message is arrived to the component. For example your `environment` header will be populated to the outbound message for each inbound message and the result will be based on a current `payload` of the request message.

Since `xsl1` bean appies SpEL result only on init phase there is no `headers` property on the current `BeanFactory` context.

Please, read more about SpEL on bean definition phase in the Spring Framework Reference Manual and about Runtime SpEL in the Spring Integration in its Manual.

And now try to explian what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thank, you Artem for your answer! I want a custom transformer, what would analyze payload, and extract by xpath some metainformation about location of xslt resource (xslt file located in remote store).   

(Russian answ: Спасибо Большое за ответ! Мне нужна динамическая трансформация сообщения, основанная на метаинформации в самом сообщении. По-этому я и стал делать кастомный трансформер. То есть он должен извлекать по xpath путь до xslt файла, который расположен в удаленном хранилище и извлекается посредством WS.)

Comment: How do you think, may be i must implement my xslt transformer as a service-activator?

Comment: That's correct thought. You can get `XsltPayloadTransformer` as base for implementation and resolve `xslResource` at runtime against each incomming message. And use that implementation as `<transformer ref="">`